# Find consecutive missing numbers from list

Tags: python, list

How can I find consecutive missing numbers from  the list below:

```
get_user_input_list = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,17,21]
missing_item_in_list = []
start = get_user_input_list[0]
stop = get_user_input_list[-1]
    
for i in range(start,stop+1):
    if i not in get_user_input_list:
       missing_item_in_list.append(i)
```

The ouput I currently get:

```
[6,9,10,16,18,19,20]
```

The ouput I would need :

```
[[6],[9,10],[16],[18,19,20]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a temporary list that will hold the number if they are consecutives, save it in the main list when there is a break

```
tmp_list = []
for i in range(start, stop + 1):
    if i not in get_user_input_list:
        if not tmp_list or tmp_list[-1] + 1 == i:
            tmp_list.append(i)
        else:
            missing_item_in_list.append(tmp_list)
            tmp_list = [i]
if tmp_list:
    missing_item_in_list.append(tmp_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very straightforward solution:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,17,21]
missing = []
for i, e in enumerate(lst[:-1]):
    if (n := lst[i+1]) - e > 1:
        missing.append(list(range(e+1, n)))
print(missing)
```

**Output:**

```
[[6], [9, 10], [16], [18, 19, 20]]
```

**Note:**

There's an implicit assumption here that the input list is sorted ascending

Answer (score 0):

```
get_user_input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 21]
missing_item_in_list = []
start = get_user_input_list[0]
stop = get_user_input_list[-1]

sublist = []
for i in range(start, stop+1):
    if i not in get_user_input_list:
        sublist.append(i)
    else:
        if len(sublist) > 0:
            missing_item_in_list.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
print(missing_item_in_list)
```

Comment: Note that `if len(sublist) > 0:` is classically written `if sublist:` in Python. In boolean context, lists evaluate to `True` if and only if they are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_user_input_list = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,17,21]
missing_item_in_list = []
start = get_user_input_list[0]
stop = get_user_input_list[-1]
temp = [] 
for i in range(start,stop+1):
    if i not in get_user_input_list:
      if not temp:
        temp.append(i)
      elif i-1 == temp[-1]:
        temp.append(i)
        continue
      else:
        missing_item_in_list.append(temp)
        temp=[i]
      
      #print(i)
      #missing_item_in_list.append(i)
missing_item_in_list.append(temp)
print(missing_item_in_list)
```

edited your code to accommodate the change in one loop itself

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
get_user_input_list = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,17,21]
missing_item_in_list = []
for i in range(len(get_user_input_list)-1):
    if (n := get_user_input_list[i]+1) not in get_user_input_list:
        missing_item_in_list.append(list(range(n, get_user_input_list[i+1])))

print(missing_item_in_list)
```

**Output**

```
[[6], [9, 10], [16], [18, 19, 20]]
```

Comment: Note: this only works in Python 3.8+ because of the walrus operator.

Comment: @AlexK Is it not reasonable to provide answers using code that's compatible with the most up-to-date version of Python? Even 3.8 is two major versions behind the latest

Comment: @AlbertWinestein I did not mean to be critical here, it was for informational purposes. For example, Google Colab that many people use is still on 3.7.

Comment: @AlexK You've just highlighted a very good reason for not using Google Colab ;-)